# How to print promised data to a webpage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, promise

I am trying to bring an array of strings from a database to a dropdown menu on a website I have created. I have everything working properly except for the final transfer of the data from the retrieval method to the website. Right now the data is in the form of a Promise, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to print out on my webpage. right now I'm just sending it to localhost:3000, I'm not at the point where I'm putting it into the dropdown yet. How would I do this ?

I've found very very little on this issue online and thus have been mainly just trying hack fixes that haven't really worked (tacking on the resolve() method, all() method). both of those resulted in syntax errors. All Var names/SQL queries have been changed btw. My latest attempt is below:

```
//code that sends the names to the webpage
 app.get('/formfetch', function(req, res) {
            const data = async() => {
                let rawDat = await dbFormFetch.getNames();
                return rawDat;
             }
            }
        const hNs = data();
        hNs.then((names) => {
                if (names === null) {
                    res.end("Error: Names list came through as null.");
                } else if (names.length > 0) {
                    resolve(names);
                    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                        res.end(names[i]);
                    }
                    res.status('200');
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                res.status('404').json(err)
                console.log("conversion of promise failed")
            })
    });



//the getNames() method  (in a different file) 
async function getNames() {
    console.log("trying to get Names");
    let query = `select NAME from NAMESTAB`;
    console.log("query: " + query);
    const binds = {};
    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, binds);
    var results = [];
    console.log("for loop in formfetch.js: ");
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        results[i] = i + ": " + result.rows[i].NAME+ ' \n';
     }
    return results;
    }
```

The res.send method from the app.get function prints out "Made it to the Web server:" on my localhost. I checked the console, and I didn't see anything hidden in the html or something like that.

**Note: all of the data that should be in the promise is in the code (I can print it to console at any point in the code), but when I put it on the website it won't print. **

Comment: Promise means that the data is not there yet. You have to wait for it until you can go on processing it. A promise cannot be converted into a String or alike. A promise gets resolved some time in the future and then there could be data which could be a string or something else.

Comment: yeah I figured that out. all of the data that should be in the promise is in the code (I can print it to console at any point in the code), but when I put it on the website it won't print.

Comment: What's with `resolve(names);`? There is no `resolve` function defined anywhere.

Comment: `data`, `rawDat`, `hNs` are all unnecessary variables or functions. Just write `dbFormFetch.getNames().then((names) => { … })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so big surprise here, I was doing it all wrong. Lesson of the day: read up on Promises and how they work before running and gunning your way through some async code. It's not as intuitive as you would hope.

```
// I only had made changes to the first of the two methods. 
app.get('/formfetch', function(req, res) {
            async function data() {
                let rawDat = await dbFormFetch.getNames();
                return rawDat;

            }
            data().then((Names) => {
                    if (Names === undefined) {
                        res.end("Error: Names list came through as null.");
                    } else if (Names.length > 0) {
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        res.status(200).json({ "names": Names });
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    res.status('404').send("name retrieval failed in server.js module")
                    console.log(err)
                    console.log("conversion of promise failed")
                })
        });
```

when you use `res.end()` , it sets the header status and renders it immutable after calling this method, so it was the wrong thing to use. Instead of this, I used the `setHeader()` method to tell the website what kind of information I'm sending it, and then filled in the content by chaining the `.json()` method to the `status()` response I sent. I've never worked with promises before and I'm fairly new to NodeJS so this was a bit of a learning curve, but hopefully this helps people who are where I was yesterday. if you're new to promises, see [this article](https://www.promisejs.org/) and [this article](https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098) before you try to use this coding tool. you'll save yourself hours of debugging and error tracing.

Comment: Let me be clear: don't copy what I did. look at what the articles do, and use that information.